# Is it safe to define Spark transformations in a function and return a new dataframe in BigData?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe `df1`. I plan to split it into two dataframes - `df2` and `df3`. The existing code flow has ALMOST the same sequence of transformations. So I want to define all those set of transformations in a function which accepts a dataframe and do those transformations and returns the transformed dataframe.

So is it safe to go with such approach (especially, with BigData) OR simply repeat the same sequence transformations two times for both of the dataframes `df2` and `df3` (this would increase code)?

Comment: Post the code you are trying to see if there is anything weir..

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 No there nothing weird in my code, so no code in this question. I just wanted to ask a conceptual doubt which I was not aware of. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem and it wouldn't affect your performance either way. Spark doesn't run your code directly. It generates a plan based on the transformations you define. These would be the same if you do them in a function or duplicate your code

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, this is fine to define a method that group several methods, you might want to be interested in the `andThen` method for clear code if you need to apply a lot of methods

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.transform()` method.

It exists in DataFrame API with the following signature :

```
def transform[U](t: (DataFrame) ⇒ DataFrame): DataFrame`
```

and in Dataset API (DataFrame is an alias of Dataset[Row] since 2.2.0 :

```
def transform[U](t: (Dataset[T]) ⇒ Dataset[U]): Dataset[U]
```

So you can define a method :

```
def mytransformation(inputDF:DataFrame):DataFrame = { 
  //transformationgo there 
  // val ouputDF = inputDF.map(...).filter(...) 
  outputDF 
}
```

or a function :

```
val mytransformation:DataFrame => DataFrame = inputDF => {  
  // val ouputDF = inputDF.map(...).filter(...)
  outputDF 
}
```

Then you can pass mytransformation to the transform method as an argument